# No puedo cambiar color del navbar

Tags: php, css

codigo de navbar.php

```css
#footer{ background-color:#848484; } .navbar-default { background-color: #ed1b2d; border-color: #7a6b6b; } .navbar-default .navbar-brand { color: #ffffff; } .navbar-default .navbar-brand:hover, .navbar-default .navbar-brand:focus {
  color: #ffffff; } .navbar-default .navbar-text { color: #ffffff; } .navbar-default .navbar-nav > li > a { color: #ffffff; } .navbar-default .navbar-nav > li > a:hover, .navbar-default .navbar-nav > li > a:focus { color: #ffffff; } .navbar-default .navbar-nav
  > .active > a, .navbar-default .navbar-nav > .active > a:hover, .navbar-default .navbar-nav > .active > a:focus { color: #ffffff; background-color: #7a6b6b; } .navbar-default .navbar-nav > .open > a, .navbar-default .navbar-nav > .open > a:hover, .navbar-default
  .navbar-nav > .open > a:focus { color: #ffffff; background-color: #7a6b6b; } .navbar-default .navbar-toggle { border-color: #7a6b6b; } .navbar-default .navbar-toggle:hover, .navbar-default .navbar-toggle:focus { background-color: #7a6b6b; } .navbar-default
  .navbar-toggle .icon-bar { background-color: #ffffff; } .navbar-default .navbar-collapse, .navbar-default .navbar-form { border-color: #ffffff; } .navbar-default .navbar-link { color: #ffffff; } .navbar-default .navbar-link:hover { color: #ffffff; }
  @media (max-width: 767px) { .navbar-default .navbar-nav .open .dropdown-menu > li > a { color: #ffffff; } .navbar-default .navbar-nav .open .dropdown-menu > li > a:hover, .navbar-default .navbar-nav .open .dropdown-menu > li > a:focus { color: #ffffff;
  } .navbar-default .navbar-nav .open .dropdown-menu > .active > a, .navbar-default .navbar-nav .open .dropdown-menu > .active > a:hover, .navbar-default .navbar-nav .open .dropdown-menu > .active > a:focus { color: #ffffff; background-color: #7a6b6b;
  } }
```

```html
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<?php
  if (isset($title))
  {
 ?>

  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
  <nav class="navbar navbar-default navbar-fixed-top " role="navigation">
    <div class="container-fluid">
      <div class="navbar-header">
        <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle collapsed" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#bs-example-navbar-collapse-1" aria-expanded="false">
        <span class="sr-only">Toggle navigation</span>
        <span class="icon-bar"></span>
        <span class="icon-bar"></span>
        <span class="icon-bar"></span>
  <span class="icon-bar"></span>
     <span class="icon-bar"></span>
   </button>
        <a class="navbar-brand">Inventario Swisslub Area TIC</a>
      </div>


      <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="bs-example-navbar-collapse-1">
        <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
          <li class="<?php if (isset($active_productos)){echo $active_productos;}?>"><a href="stock.php"><i class='glyphicon glyphicon-barcode'></i> Inventario</a></li>
          <li class="<?php if (isset($active_categoria)){echo $active_categoria;}?>"><a href="categorias.php"><i class='glyphicon glyphicon-tags'></i> Categorías</a></li>
          <li class="<?php if (isset($active_usuarios)){echo $active_usuarios;}?>"><a href="usuarios.php"><i  class='glyphicon glyphicon-user'></i> Usuarios</a></li>
          <li class="<?php if (isset($active_prestamos)){echo $active_Prestamos;}?>"><a href="prestamos.php"><i class='glyphicon glyphicon-refresh'></i>Prestamos</a></li>
          <li class="<?php if (isset($active_equipos)){echo $active_equipos;}?>"><a href="Asignacion de equipos.php"><i class='glyphicon glyphicon-phone'></i>Asignacion Equipos</a></li>
        </ul>
        <ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-right">
          <li class="<?php if (isset($active_equipos)){echo $active_equipos;}?>"><a href="Help desk.php">Help desk<i class='glyphicon glyphicon-question-sign'></i></a></li>
          <li><a href="login.php?logout"><i class='glyphicon glyphicon-off'></i> Salir</a></li>
        </ul>
      </div>
    </div>
  </nav>
  <?php
  }
 ?>
```

Comment: Por favor implementa tu código para saber cual es tu problema y que es lo que quieres... !

Comment: sya lo estoy ingresando pero me toca linea por llinea aplicarle la sangria :)

Comment: Tu problema esta en la variable $active_equipos, la estas llamando tres veces, entonces tres elementos del navbar se marcan como activos

Comment: si un pequeño error pero eso no es lo que yo quiero es que no me cambia de color cuando le doy click a prestamos y asignacion de equipos

Comment: Por ejemplo en tu pagina prestamos tienes que tener estos campos o algo asi:       $active_facturas="";
 $active_productos="";
 $active_clientes="";
 $active_usuarios=""; 
 **$active_prestamos="active";** entonces en la paginas que estes tiene que tener active y los demas "";

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Tu error es que no estas usando muy bien los selectores, te dejo un [link donde puedes aprender sobre selectores y como modificar bootstrap](http://librosweb.es/libro/bootstrap_3/capitulo_1/personalizando_bootstrap.html)

Y continuando con tu pregunta solo cambie la forma la forma en que intentabas llegar al navbar, use esto nav.navbar para acceder a ella.

```css
#footer{
background-color:black;
}

nav.navbar {
  background-color: #ae2822;
}

.navbar .navbar-brand {
  color: #f9f7f7;
}

.navbar .navbar-brand:hover,
.navbar .navbar-brand:focus {
  color: #c91b1b;
}

.navbar .navbar-text {
  color: #f9f7f7;
}

.navbar .navbar-nav .nav-link {
  color: #f9f7f7;
  border-radius: .25rem;
  margin: 0 0.25em;
}

.navbar .navbar-nav .nav-link:not(.disabled):hover,
.navbar .navbar-nav .nav-link:not(.disabled):focus {
  color: #c91b1b;
}

.navbar .navbar-nav .nav-item.active .nav-link,
.navbar .navbar-nav .nav-item.active .nav-link:hover,
.navbar .navbar-nav .nav-item.active .nav-link:focus,
.navbar .navbar-nav .nav-item.show .nav-link,
.navbar .navbar-nav .nav-item.show .nav-link:hover,
.navbar .navbar-nav .nav-item.show .nav-link:focus {
  color: #c91b1b;
  background-color: #f9f9f9;
}

.navbar .navbar-toggle {
  border-color: #f9f9f9;
}

.navbar .navbar-toggle:hover,
.navbar .navbar-toggle:focus {
  background-color: #f9f9f9;
}

.navbar .navbar-toggle .navbar-toggler-icon {
  color: #f9f7f7;
}

.navbar .navbar-collapse,
.navbar .navbar-form {
  border-color: #f9f7f7;
}

.navbar .navbar-link {
  color: #f9f7f7;
}

.navbar .navbar-link:hover {
  color: #c91b1b;
}

@media (max-width: 575px) {
  .navbar-expand-sm .navbar-nav .show .dropdown-menu .dropdown- item {
    color: #f9f7f7;
  }
  .navbar-expand-sm .navbar-nav .show .dropdown-menu .dropdown-item:hover,
  .navbar-expand-sm .navbar-nav .show .dropdown-menu .dropdown- item:focus {
    color: #c91b1b;
  }
  .navbar-expand-sm .navbar-nav .show .dropdown-menu .dropdown- item.active {
    color: #c91b1b;
    background-color: #f9f9f9;
  }
}

@media (max-width: 767px) {
  .navbar-expand-md .navbar-nav .show .dropdown-menu .dropdown- item {
    color: #f9f7f7;
  }
  .navbar-expand-md .navbar-nav .show .dropdown-menu .dropdown- item:hover,
  .navbar-expand-md .navbar-nav .show .dropdown-menu .dropdown- item:focus {
    color: #c91b1b;
  }
  .navbar-expand-md .navbar-nav .show .dropdown-menu .dropdown- item.active {
    color: #c91b1b;
    background-color: #f9f9f9;
  }
}

@media (max-width: 991px) {
  .navbar-expand-lg .navbar-nav .show .dropdown-menu .dropdown- item {
    color: #f9f7f7;
  }
  .navbar-expand-lg .navbar-nav .show .dropdown-menu .dropdown-item:hover,
  .navbar-expand-lg .navbar-nav .show .dropdown-menu .dropdown- item:focus {
    color: #c91b1b;
  }
  .navbar-expand-lg .navbar-nav .show .dropdown-menu .dropdown-item.active {
    color: #c91b1b;
    background-color: #f9f9f9;
  }
}

@media (max-width: 1199px) {
  .navbar-expand-xl .navbar-nav .show .dropdown-menu .dropdown- item {
    color: #f9f7f7;
  }
  .navbar-expand-xl .navbar-nav .show .dropdown-menu .dropdown- item:hover,
  .navbar-expand-xl .navbar-nav .show .dropdown-menu .dropdown- item:focus {
    color: #c91b1b;
  }
  .navbar-expand-xl .navbar-nav .show .dropdown-menu .dropdown- item.active {
    color: #c91b1b;
    background-color: #f9f9f9;
  }
}

.navbar-expand .navbar-nav .show .dropdown-menu .dropdown-item {
  color: #f9f7f7;
}

.navbar-expand .navbar-nav .show .dropdown-menu .dropdown-item:hover,
.navbar-expand .navbar-nav .show .dropdown-menu .dropdown-item:focus {
  color: #c91b1b;
}

.navbar-expand .navbar-nav .show .dropdown-menu .dropdown-item.active {
  color: #c91b1b;
  background-color: #f9f9f9;
}


}
.thumb-name {
  font-weight: bold;
  display: block;
}
.stock-counter {
  opacity: 0.8;
  position: absolute;
  margin-top: 5px;
  right: 21px;
}
.badge {
  display: inline-block;
  min-width: 10px;
  padding: 3px 7px;
  font-size: 12px;
  font-weight: 700;
  line-height: 1;
  color: #fff;
  text-align: center;
  white-space: nowrap;
  vertical-align: middle;
  background-color: #777;
  border-radius: 10px;
}
.low-stock-alert {
  opacity: 0.8;
  position: absolute;
  margin-top: 5px;
  left: 21px;
  color: red;
}
.item-quantity {
  font-size: 40px;
}
.current-stock {
  font-size: 99px;
  font-weight: bold;
}
.item-number {
  font-size: 20px;
}
.item-title {
  font-size: 23px;
  font-weight: bold;
}
.item-price {
  font-size: 23px;
  font-weight: bold;
  color: #388e3c;
}
.pagination>.active>a,
.pagination>.active>a:focus,
.pagination>.active>a:hover,
.pagination>.active>span,
.pagination>.active>span:focus,
.pagination>.active>span:hover {
  z-index: 3;
  color: #fff;
  cursor: default;
  background-color: #3c763d;
  border-color: #ccc;
}
a {
  color: #3c763d;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />

<nav class="navbar navbar-default ">
  <div class="container-fluid">
    <!-- Brand and toggle get grouped for better mobile display -->
    <div class="navbar-header">
      <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle collapsed" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#bs-example-navbar-collapse-1" aria-expanded="false">
        <span class="sr-only">Toggle navigation</span>
        <span class="icon-bar"></span>
        <span class="icon-bar"></span>
        <span class="icon-bar"></span>
      </button>
      <a class="navbar-brand" href="#">Simple Stock</a>
    </div>

    <!-- Collect the nav links, forms, and other content for toggling -->
    <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="bs-example-navbar-collapse-1">
      <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
        <li class="<?php if (isset($active_productos)){echo $active_productos;}?>"><a href="stock.php"><i class='glyphicon glyphicon-barcode'></i> Inventario</a></li>
        <li class="<?php if (isset($active_categoria)){echo $active_categoria;}?>"><a href="categorias.php"><i class='glyphicon glyphicon-tags'></i> Categorías</a></li>
        <li class="<?php if (isset($active_usuarios)){echo $active_usuarios;}?>"><a href="usuarios.php"><i  class='glyphicon glyphicon-user'></i> Usuarios</a></li>
      </ul>
      <ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-right">
        <li><a href="http://obedalvarado.pw/contacto/" target='_blank'><i class='glyphicon glyphicon-envelope'></i> Soporte</a></li>
        <li><a href="login.php?logout"><i class='glyphicon glyphicon-off'></i> Salir</a></li>
      </ul>
    </div>
    <!-- /.navbar-collapse -->
  </div>
  <!-- /.container-fluid -->
</nav>
Editada: solo tienes que darle un id al footer, y 
despues darle el color que quieras: te dejo el ejemplo,
 si te fijas llame id="footer" a el div y 
luego aplique css a ese id, 
#footer{background-color:black}

<div class="navbar navbar-default navbar-fixed-bottom" id="footer">
  <div class="container">
    <p class="navbar-text pull-left">&copy
      <?php echo date('Y');?> - Swisslub soluciones Integrales
    </p>
    <div class="navbar-text pull-right">
      <?php  echo  $_SESSION['firstname'];?> &nbsp &nbsp &nbsp &nbsp &nbsp
      <?php  echo  $_SESSION['user_permision'];?>

    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="container">

  </div>
</div>

<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.3/jquery.min.js">
</script>

<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-
   0mSbJDEHialfmuBBQP6A4Qrprq5OVfW37PRR3j5ELqxss1yVqOtnepnHVP9aJ7xS" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
```

Comment: no no cambio el el navbar

Comment: No te funciona porque tu css esta definido para el navbar, y en tu html no lo tienes definido asi.

Comment: Ya esta editada la respuesta.

Comment: pero igual no funciona

Comment: Como te digo, tu problema es el html. Podrias pasar el link del navbar que quieres implementar?

Comment: no ya gracias solo fue actualizar el nombre del css y ya bn mi pregunta ahora es que quiero cambiar el footer de color pero si lo hago tambien cambia el navbar como haria eso

Comment: Tendrias que subir el footer para ver el codigo, imagino que los estas llamando igual al navbar por eso se cambian los dos

Comment: ya subi el footer

Comment: que me recomiendas ghacerlo directamente en plan .footer <footer> oo hay alguna forma  mejor en css

Comment: Revisa mi respuesta, ya la actualice con un ejemplo

Comment: bua tio grande crack muchas gracias por la ayuda y perdon por la ignorancia XD muchas gracias de verdad

Comment: ¡En hora buena! Si soluciono tus problemas puedes marcarla como solucion.

Comment: oye una ultima pregunta y no vuelvas a saber de mi jaja tengo los 5 link en el navbar pero solo 3 me aparecen con el efecto de  click osea cambia el fondo pero no se como modificarlo jeje gracias para que me aparezcan el efecto en los cinco

Comment: Tendrias que subir codigo, no puedo ayudarte a ciegas

Comment: ok ya subi el codigo css y el .php

Answer (score 0):

Tal vez te sirva

nav.navbar {
    background-color: #CC1414;
}

Visit http://librosweb.es/foro/pregunta/513/cambiar-color-y-tipo-de-letra-a-la-barra-de-navegacion-de-bootstrap/

Answer (score 0):

Usas mal los selectores. Ten en cuenta que unos selectores tienen preferencia a otros. Por ejemplo si estás apuntando con un selector de etiqueta por ejemplo  y cambiando el background, si hay un selector de id como en el ejemplo..los cambios del selector id van por encima de los cambios del selector de etiqueta. Mira mejor esa parte